# Sub actions (or viewlets) in Express and EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In many MVC frameworks there is an option to invoke actions from view. For ASP.NET MVC it is called [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in other frameworks such feature is called SubActions, Viewlets etc.

I need to place in EJS layout file list of latest news (comming from DB) and this should be visible in a sidebar on all views that use this layout. I don't want to duplicate logic of selecting and passing news list on every route.

Is there any clear way to do this in Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any RenderAction implementation, but using [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) data can be shared between routes (list of latest news, for example).